# Why is this array undefined in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, undefined

I have the following code, to set up the mines in a minesweeper game, but I keep getting an error in the plantMines() function, "TypeError: data[randomx] is undefined". I'm new to React, so perhaps I'm missing something simple, but I just cannot see where the problem is.

```
initBoardData(height, width, mines) {
    let data = this.createEmptyArray(height, width);
    data = this.plantMines(data, height, width, mines);
    return data;
}

// Create array of grid
createEmptyArray(height, width) {
    let data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        data.push([]);
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            data[i][j] = {
                x: i,
                y: j,
                isMine: false,
                neighbour: 0,
                isRevealed: false,
                isEmpty: false,
                isFlagged: false
            };
        }
    }
    return data;
}

// Place mines on board
plantMines(data, height, width, mines) {
    let randomx, randomy, minesPlanted = 0;

    while (minesPlanted < mines) {
        randomx = this.getRandomNumber(width);
        randomy = this.getRandomNumber(height);

        if (!(data[randomx][randomy].isMine)) {    //--ERROR ON THIS LINE
            data[randomx][randomy].isMine = true;
            minesPlanted++;
        }
    }
    return (data);
}

getRandomNumber(dimension) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1 % dimension);
}
```

EDIT: codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/minesweeper-luono?file=/src/Board.js

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/minesweeper-luono?file=/src/Board.js

Comment: Your demo has other errors. Please fix those also except `if (!(data[randomx][randomy].isMine))` which is the original issue.

Comment: @T.Baer Fix `<Board height={height} width={width} mines={mines} />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. `height` and `width` were not properly defined, so `randomx` and `randomy` were being taken as strings, not numbers, thus the array definition error.

Answer (score 3):

You have error in getRandomNumber - missing parentheses:

```
getRandomNumber(dimension) {
    return Math.floor(((Math.random() * 1000) + 1) % dimension);
  }
```

There is one more problem though, use the solution that @dellink presented too:

```
randomx = this.getRandomNumber(height);
randomy = this.getRandomNumber(width);
```

You have to make **BOTH** changes, so it starts working!!

Comment: Thanks, that hasn't solved the original error though

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a new error now? I tested it out and it seemed to work.

Comment: When I was making my tests, i was using a square - 10/10, but when you have rectangular dimension, the error was triggered. Now it got fixed.

Comment: Hmm that still hasn't changed anything for me

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to not existing index of the array. Thus; you are getting `undefined` error. 
You can use below or @Enchew's answer.

```
getRandomNumber(dimension) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(dimension));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try change in this way

```
randomx = this.getRandomNumber(height);
randomy = this.getRandomNumber(width);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though it didn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you should access your array like: data[randomy][randomx]

Comment: Switching them doesn't solve the error, just changes it to "TypeError: data[randomy] is undefined"